# Cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: c#

estou com erro ao instanciar o serviço. Ele é genérico e preciso dele assim, pois posso utilizar qualquer entidade nele. Quando inicio o serviço no hibernate, preciso passar a entidade que vou trabalhar para utilizar o mapeamento do banco. Ou seja, quando instancio o serviço passando TipoDocumento ou Documento, o ele utiliza o mapeamento da entidade TipoDocumento ou Documento. Eu só vou utilizar métodos e propriedades da entidade pai, só preciso utilizar a classe filha para acessar o mapeamento da tabela certa que vou pesquisar.
nas telas normais, eu sobrescrevo os métodos passando a entidade que preciso, mas na tela de pesquisa, preciso fazer tudo na mesma tela, pois é inviável fazer uma tela para cada pesquisa

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ServicoCadastroMestre'
>   to 'ServicoCadastro'

```js
public class TipoDocumento : CadastroMestre
{
}

public class ServicoCadastroMestre<T> : ServicoCadastro<T> where T : CadastroMestre
{
}

public abstract class ViewCadastroMestre<T> : ViewCadastro<T> where T : CadastroMestre
{
    public abstract ServicoCadastro<T> GetServico();

    public abstract T GetEntidade();
}

public class ViewPesquisa : ViewCadastroMestre<CadastroMestre>
{
    public override CadastroMestre GetEntidade()
    {
        return new TipoDocumento();
    }

////o problema está aqui    
public override ServicoCadastro<CadastroMestre> GetServico()
    {
        return new ServicoCadastroMestre<TipoDocumento>();
    }
}

///////aqui funciona normalmente///////
public class ViewTipoDocumento : ViewCadastroMestre<TipoDocumento>
{
    public override TipoDocumento GetEntidade()
    {
        return new TipoDocumento();
    }
 
    public override ServicoCadastro<TipoDocumento> GetServico()
    {
        return new ServicoCadastroMestre<TipoDocumento>();
    }
}
```

Comment: e `return new ServicoCadastro<TipoDocumento>();`  funciona ?

Comment: da o mesmo erro. ServicoCadastroMestre herda de ServicoCadastro, que é abstrato... mas já testei tirar de abstrato e instanciar ele, mas da o mesmo erro...

Comment: talvez fosse o caso de usar uma interface.

Comment: não visualizei...

o problema está em passar TipoDocumento em  return new ServicoCadastroMestre<TipoDocumento>(); onde é esperado CadastroMestre em ServicoCadastro<CadastroMestre>

public override ServicoCadastro<CadastroMestre> GetServico()
    {
        return new ServicoCadastroMestre<TipoDocumento>();
    }
}

a intenção e onde eu passo TipoDocumento, eu ter um case onde posso passar qualquer entidade com herança a CadastroMestre

Comment: acredito que não será possível. em interfaces genéricas você até pode usar os conceitos de covariância e contravariancia, mas em tipos assim, teria que ter uma conversão explícita e acredito que terá problemas ao converter um tipo mais específico em um tipo menos específico.

Comment: realmente não consegui. como vim do delphi, acho que ele é muito mais aberto a heranças. por conta disso, precisava fazer muito tratamento de erro. no c#, não precisa tratar nada. obrigado pela ajuda